# sqlite3 max function

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple database of two tables, User,Customer. Both these have a smallint id.
I ran this command

```
 select max(u.id,c.id) as maxthing from Users u join Customers c;
```

I got pretty much all the id's in both tables. 
I tried looking at the docs for max but it dosent say I can pass a second parameter.
Can someone explain what is happening here, what happens when I pass in a second parameter to max()?

Comment: The actual question is what you are trying to do here.

Comment: *The multi-argument max() function returns the argument with the maximum value*

Comment: This is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc) in the documentation.

Comment: @juergen d -I'm just playing around with the functions, I'm trying to learn about it.

Comment: @AlexK. I would have assumed that but its not what I am seeing as I get all the id's in the table.

Comment: The surprising thing is that the query executes because it is invalid SQL as you forgot the join condition.

Comment: @CL. This is helpfull, however I have in my user table three rows with each row of an id 0-2. While in my Customers table I have two rows with id's 0-1. When I execute the sql above I get [1,1,2,2,0,1]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQLite's [join syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) is quite loose (you could also use `FROM a, b ON a.id=b.id`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are making a Cartesian join , each record joins to each records so got are multiplying the results. You need to add a join relation :

```
 select max(u.id,c.id) as maxthing
 from Users u
 join Customers c
  ON(u.ID = c.User_ID)
```

Comment: Are you saying that my original SQL is incorrect because I lack the ON condition for this operation and the return I was getting will always return the data in this way because my SQL is incorrect?

Comment: @MrClamps There are two problems: `max()` with two parameters is not an aggregate function, and you did not actually join anything. You asked only for the first. And without an actual goal, nobody can suggest a better query.